# Stop vertical movement when user flings on Horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recycler-view within motion layout. Sometimes when I do a horizontal swipe, the page starts scrolling in the vertical direction. This happens when we do a diagonal fling.

I want something like Google Play where horizontal recycler-views can defend slightly diagonal vertical swipes. BTW setting `nestedscrollEnabled` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is quite a nice article regarding all the RecycleView scroll behavior and the issue itself. Checkout Rúben Sousa [article](https://rubensousa.com/2019/08/16/nested_recyclerview_part1/). Solution is quite easy, try to use adopted RecyclerView:

```
/**
 * A RecyclerView that only handles scroll events with the same orientation of its LayoutManager.
 * Avoids situations where nested recyclerviews don't receive touch events properly:
 */
public class OrientationAwareRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private float lastX = 0.0f;
    private float lastY = 0.0f;
    private boolean scrolling = false;

    public OrientationAwareRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public OrientationAwareRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public OrientationAwareRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,
                                        int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                scrolling = newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        final LayoutManager lm = getLayoutManager();
        if (lm == null) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
        }

        boolean allowScroll = true;

        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                lastX = e.getX();
                lastY = e.getY();
                // If we were scrolling, stop now by faking a touch release
                if (scrolling) {
                    MotionEvent newEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(e);
                    newEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
                    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(newEvent);
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // We're moving, so check if we're trying
                // to scroll vertically or horizontally so we don't intercept the wrong event.
                float currentX = e.getX();
                float currentY = e.getY();
                float dx = Math.abs(currentX - lastX);
                float dy = Math.abs(currentY - lastY);
                allowScroll = dy > dx ? lm.canScrollVertically() : lm.canScrollHorizontally();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!allowScroll) {
            return false;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already fixed the issue but forget about that i asked a question here. Anyway i'll accept your solution since it matches how i did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- This Work perfect for me.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="more"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_single_card.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Screenshot of RecyclerView]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); 
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); 
        rv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                    }

                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

That code prevent scroll vertically when you scroll with your horizontal recyclerview.